# defaultDate for agendaWeek View in Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

The defaultDate option is only working for agendaDay is it possible to set defaultDate option to be apply for agendaWeek option ?
i.e, if i set defaultDate : '2017-06-06' the week should start from given date.

Comment: it will cause the calendar to display the week which _contains_ the defaultDate. Same for month view, or any other view which covers more than one day. Have a read of this, it may do what you need: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/visibleRange/

Comment: It works for me... Thanks @ADyson  :)